# Change name and id in form

Tags: forms, symfony

I would change my Return form

I create form with a loop inside my twig, and I would like to change the name and id fields

eg

```
<input type="text" id="foo_1" name="foo_1[title]" maxlength="255">
```

I want to add an index like I did for the id of the form {{loop.index}}

I might have to pass something to the constructor of my form, but I have not found anything that has helped me

Answer (score 1):

For Now i do It:

My controller

```
foreach($fotos as $key => $foto){

            $array_fotos[] = array(
                "form" => $this->createForm(new \My\FotoBundle\Form\FotoType($key), $fotos[$key])->createView(),

            );
        }
```

In My FormType i do this

```
class FotoType extends AbstractType
{

    protected $key;

    public function __construct($chiave) {
        $this->key = $chiave;
    }

    .....


    public function getName()
    {
        return 'form_gestione_foto_'.$this->key;
    }
}
```